# Is there a faster way to loop through numpy matrix

Tags: python, numpy, poisson

have been trying on how to calculate poisson probabilities for both teams to score, but they don't add up to zero when add up possible scorelines and having a range of 0 to 6 isn't even enough.

```
from scipy.stats import poisson
import numpy as np
home_goals_vector = poisson(1.23).pmf(np.arange(0, 6))
away_goals_vector = poisson(2.23).pmf(np.arange(0, 6))
print(home_goals_vector)
m = np.outer(home_goals_vector, away_goals_vector)
print(m[1, 1] + m[2, 1] + m[3, 1] + m[4, 1] + m[1, 2] + m[2, 2] + m[2, 3] + m[2, 4] + m[3, 2] + m[3, 3] + m[3, 4] + m[4, 1] + m[4, 2] + m[4, 4] + m[1, 3] + m[1, 4])
print(np.sum(m))
```

Now, I know the variable m contains the possible scores and the probabilities, is there a faster way to do this cause I need all possible scores so that scorelines that both have no zero and scorelines that do have zero, if i add up their probabilities I get 100%

Comment: The Poisson distribution is defined over the natural numbers, so any finite sum of these products of probabilities is not going to add to 100%. If you want it to sum to close to 100%, then pick larger interval of outcomes.

Comment: Just multiplying the probabilities to get the joint probabilities assumes that they are independent. Are you sure that is what you intend to do?

Comment: I already know all that, that was for an example, if I use a range of 0 to 30 I might get 100% if they're added, I asked this question cause on the seventh line, I can't keep writing all the probabilities if I used 0 to 30 range.

Comment: Can you describe what subset of the probabilities you are wanting to sum? I assume not all of them, otherwise `np.sum` would be adequate.

Comment: On the fifth line, you will notice that probabilities don't have a 0 index or column.... I don't know how explain that. I excluded scores where there isn't a zero in it

Comment: It has a 0 index; `home_goals_vector[0]` exists. The output of `poisson(1.23).pmf(np.arange(0, 6))` is a NumPy array with shape `(6,)`, so there are not two index sets until you take the outer product.

Comment: I don't follow your meaning of "I excluded scores where there isn't a zero in it". Running `np.all(np.outer(home_goals_vector, away_goals_vector) != 0)` I get `True`.

Comment: But I already know that what I meant was I manually selected those without index 0 look at my print statement you will understand. Is there a way to loop and select rows without a zero, I'm calculating this with football scorelines in mind.

Comment: Often it is preferable that you explain the main thing you want to accomplish rather than have us read your code. This is partly due to the [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

Comment: If you are looking to sum the entries where the index is not zero, that is taking the sum which excludes the first column and the first row. This can be taken with `np.sum(m[1:, 1:])`, but that is not equivalent to your manually coded sum.

Comment: Sorry about that, I thought I explained what I wanted to do after I showed the code. Can you help me?

Comment: I cannot be of any help at this time. I don't understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: Ok, am a newb, but let me visualize it for you the variable m spits out a numpy matrix, what I want to exclude is the top side of the matrix and the leftmost side of the matrix. I dunno if I explained this well.

Comment: That sounds like computing `np.sum(m[1:, 1:])`, which excludes the zeroeth (i.e. first) column and the zeroeth (i.e. first) row. See [w3school](https://www.w3schools.com/python/numpy/numpy_array_slicing.asp) for an explanation of the syntax.

Comment: Yes exactly! Will that work?

Comment: Yeah, when I put `<stuff>` I mean something that is literal code. This is a frequently-used convention on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some deliberation in the comments, it seems that you are wanting to exclude the zeroeth row and column from the summation over the outer product of the two probability vectors.

This can be done by substituting `np.sum(m)` for `np.sum(m[1:, 1:])` in your code example. This is an example of using NumPy's slicing notation, which is similar to Matlab's slicing notation (by design).